# Derivatives in time and phasor domains do not match

Tags: formula-derivation

Given that voltage can be represented in the time domain as the following:

$$V(t) = \vec{\mathbf{|V|}}\cos{(\omega t + \phi_V)}$$

It can be shown that in the phasor domain, this is the equivalent expression for V(t):

$$V(t) = \frac{1}{2}\vec{\mathbf{V}}e^{j\omega t} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{\mathbf{V^*}}e^{-j\omega t}$$

The time derivative in the first case is:

$$V'(t) = \vec{\mathbf{|V|}}(-w)\sin{(\omega t + \phi_V)}$$

My solution for the time derivative in the second case is:

$$V'(t) = \frac{1}{2}\vec{\mathbf{V}}(j \omega)e^{j\omega t} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{\mathbf{V^*}}(-j \omega)e^{-j\omega t}$$

$$V'(t) = (jw)(\frac{1}{2}\vec{\mathbf{V}}e^{j\omega t} - \frac{1}{2}\vec{\mathbf{V^*}}e^{-j\omega t})$$

Subtraction of the complex conjugates yields 2 times the imaginary part:

$$V'(t) = (jw)(2*Im{\frac{1}{2}\vec{\mathbf{V}}e^{j\omega t}})$$

$$V'(t) = \vec{\mathbf{|V|}}(jw)\sin{(\omega t + \phi_V)}$$

It appears that the derivatives vary by a factor of j.
What is happening here?

Answer (score -1):

It did not occur to me that taking the imaginary part would introduce a factor of j in the second to last step.  Problem solved.  Thanks.

Clarification edit:  The difference of complex conjugates is 2j times the imaginary part, not just 2 times.  This is because Re{a+bj} = a and Im{a+bj} = b.  Then (a+bj)-(a-bj) = 2bj.

Comment: Hey. Good that you've solved your problem in short period of time. I feel it is maybe because you spent good time on formulating your question. Good job! I would suggest you to edit your answer and clarify it so that if anybody landed here with same problem can get a good answer for the same good question. BTW, welcome to EE.SE.